# Select de uma tabela dentro de uma celula de outra tabela

Tags: sql-server, select, table, sql-server-2012

No `SQL SERVER 2012` é possível construir uma tabela que em uma das suas colunas contenham o resultado de outra tabela?

A chave mestra seria a referência.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Assim não, mas pode ser guardar um `array` na coluna, separando os resultados por vírgula talvez.

Comment: Você precisa disso para apresentar o resultado em algum relatório?

Comment: Sim @cantoni, preciso para um relatório.

Comment: @dHEKU, então creio que você está misturando as responsabilidades. Este tipo de coisa que você precisa deve ser resolvido na visão (relatório, HTML, etc). O SQL deve apenas fornecer os dados e não formatá-los da maneira que o usuário deseja visualizá-los.

Comment: Obrigado @cantoni, realmente estava pensando ontem e o que precisa ser feito é no php, fazer uma rotina lá dentro. Qual a melhor coisa pra fazer com a pergunta? Fechar?

Comment: Isso aí. Resolva isso em outra camada. Sobre a pergunta, vou sinalizá-la e os moderadores farão alguma coisa.